# How to plot a video in a label in qml?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I want to show an avi video in a qml label using mplayer, but I dont know how.

something like:

> mplayer -slave -osdlevel 0 -vf scale=1920:1052 -ss 0 ../video.avi

Comment: just wondering, why exactly in a label?

Comment: I see a code that the person do this in QTGui in a Qlabel, so I think that in a label that is the equivalent of an QLabel will works.

Comment: @henriquevital Could you provide the link to this code or comment?